# Among any $5$ vertices there is a vertex connected to $4$ others. What is the minimum number of edges in such a graph with 40 vertices?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

> In an undirected graph with $40$ vertices among any $5$ vertices there is a vertex connected to $4$ other vertices. Tell the minimum number of edges a graph satisfying this property can have.

I got stuck with this problem. I tried applying some sort of induction or trying to solve for numbers less than $5$ and then generalize but I cannot really come up with anything.

Could you provide some hints please?

Comment: The wording is a bit ambiguous:  does "connected to $4$ other vertices" mean _the_ other $4$ in the set of $5$?  Or does it meany _any_ other $4$ in the entire graph?

Comment: I see a different ambiguity to the ones already mentioned. Is it "*connected to **exactly** 4 other vertices*" or "*connected to **at least** 4 other vertices*"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result depends on what "isolated" means in the complementary question, corresponding to two interpretations of "connected" in the original question.

> In an undirected graph with $40$ vertices, among any $5$ vertices there is an *isolated* vertex. What is the maximum number of edges under this condition?

If vertices are "connected" by individual edges alone, "isolated" means "degree $0$ in the induced subgraph" and the following argument applies. Suppose that five vertices $v_1,\dots,v_5$ in the complementary graph are linked by the edges $v_1v_2,v_2v_3,v_4v_5$. None of the vertices is isolated, so to maximise the edge count in the complement, all the edges have to be non-adjacent, i.e. the complement consists of $20$ disjoint edges, and the original graph must have at least $\frac{40×39}2-20=760$ edges. (That is, the minimal admissible graph is $K_{40}$ minus a perfect matching.)

If vertices are "connected" in the sense of connected components, the complement cannot have any connected component of five or more vertices, and the number of edges is maximised by ten disjoint copies of $K_4$, having $60$ edges in total; the original graph has at least $\frac{40×39}2-60=720$ edges.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something...  You're saying the answer to the OP question is take $K_{40}$, group the $40$ nodes into $10$ groups of $4$, and in each group delete the $K_4$ edges?  But then if you take a set of $5$ with $2$ from one group and $3$ from another, none of the $5$ is connected the other $4$.

Comment: hmm... I really don't understand your Answer then. :(  OK, I am getting mre and more confused.  Do you interpret "$u$ is connected to $v$" as "$\{u,v\}$ is an edge" (i.e. direct) or "$u,v$ in the same connected component"?

Comment: OK, I also thought "connected" meant "connected by an edge".  If we use your construction on $8$ nodes, the complementary graph $G'$ is two disjoint copies of $K_4$, and so the complement to $G'$ is the bipartite $K_{4,4}$, am I right?  But $K_{4,4}$ does not satisfy the OP requirement that any subset of $5$ nodes has one node directly connected to _the_ other $4$ in the subset.  (E.g. take the $5$-subset as $2$ from one side and $3$ from the other.)  What am I missing?

Comment: @antkam I've added both interpretations to my answer anyway.

Comment: Good correction!